# how can i select and highlight outerText from contenteditable tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, internet-explorer

I have a contenteditable P,How can i select and highlight  outer text from Div

My mouse focus starts from “selectionstart”, but I can't focus end on “selectionend"

```
<div> <p contenteditable ="true">selectionStart</p> </div> selectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the `p` tag with `document.querySelector('p')` and get its `outerText` property:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('p').outerText);
```

```html
<div> <p contenteditable ="true">selectionStart</p> </div> selectionEnd
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give a detailed description of my question,
My mouse focus starts from “selectionstart”, but I can't focus end on “selectionend"